# Error: Couldn't drop privileges: User is missing UID (see mail_uid setting)

Tags: debian, dovecot, debian-buster

I have an email system that is setup loosely around the ISPMail guides here - https://workaround.org/ispmail/buster/

I am trying to setup a script for automatic password scheme migration, but I'm running into issues.  I've been following guides similiar to this: https://wiki.dovecot.org/HowTo/ConvertPasswordSchemes

Whenever I enable userdb prefetch, the `Couldn't drop privileges: User is missing UID (see mail_uid setting)` error appears.

My user_query and password_query are as follows:

`user_query = SELECT user, \
  concat('*:bytes=', quota) AS quota_rule, \
  '/var/vmail/%d/%n' AS home, \
  5000 AS uid, 5000 AS gid \
  FROM users WHERE user='%u';`

`password_query = SELECT user, password, \
  '%w' AS userdb_plain_pass, \
  concat('*:bytes=', quota) AS quota_rule, \
  '/var/vmail/%d/%n' AS home, \
  5000 AS uid, 5000 AS gid \
  FROM users WHERE user='%u';`

I have the following configuration in place: (In this order)

`passdb {
  driver = sql
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
}
userdb {
  driver = prefetch
}
userdb {
  driver = sql
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
}`

Looking at the debug logs, when I remove the prefetch and everything works as expected:

`Jan  5 15:21:38 m1 dovecot: auth: Debug: master userdb out: USER#0114090494977#011aaron@example.com#011plain_pass=Password1234#011quota_rule=*:bytes=0#011home=/var/vmail/example.com/aaron#011uid=5000#011gid=5000#011auth_token=bdxxxxx`

However, when prefetch is enabled, it's not getting the uid and gid in the passdb out:

`Jan  5 15:18:36 m1 dovecot: auth: Debug: master userdb out: USER#0113382444033#011aaron@example.com#011plain_pass=Password1234#011auth_token=bdxxxx`

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue when using prefetch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my passdb query was missing the `userdb_` prefixes.  Adjusting it as follows solved the problem.

```
password_query = SELECT user, password, \
  '%w' AS userdb_plain_pass, \
   concat('*:bytes=', quota) AS quota_rule, \
   '/var/vmail/%d/%n' AS home, \
   5000 AS userdb_uid, 5000 AS userdb_gid \
   FROM users WHERE user='%u';
```

Dovecot [Documentation on *Prefetch User Database*](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/prefetch_userdb/):

> Prefetch basically works by requiring that the passdb returns the
>   userdb information in extra fields with `userdb_` prefixes. For example
>   if a userdb typically returns `uid`, `gid` and `home` fields, the passdb
>   would have to return `userdb_uid`, `userdb_gid` and `userdb_home` fields.